# Multi-threaded cURL with SSL and redirect

Tags: php, multithreading, ssl, curl, scraper

I have very simple scraper now does what I need, but it's very slow it scrapes 2 pictures in 3 seconds what I need to do is at least 1000 pictures in a few seconds.

This is the code I use now

```
    <?php
require_once('config.php');

//Calling PHasher class file.
include_once('classes/phasher.class.php');
$I = PHasher::Instance();

//Prevent execution timeout.
set_time_limit(0);

//Solving SSL Problem.
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

//Check if the database contains hashed pictures or if it's empty, Then start from the latest hashed picture or start from 4.
$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fid FROM images ORDER BY fid DESC LIMIT 1;");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){

    $max_fid = mysqli_fetch_row($check);

    $fid = $max_fid[0]+1;
} else {
    $fid = 4;
}

$deletedProfile = "https://z-1-static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif";

//Infinte while loop to fetch profiles pictures and save them inside avatar folder.
$initial = $fid;

while($fid = $initial){

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fid.'/picture?width=378&height=378';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow the redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // no needs to pass the headers to the data stream
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // get the resource without a body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // accept any server certificate
    curl_exec($ch);

    // get the last used URL
    $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close($ch);

    if($lastUrl == $deletedProfile){
        $initial++;
    }else{
        $imageUrl = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        $savedImage = dirname(__file__).'/avatar/image.jpg';
        file_put_contents($savedImage, $imageUrl);

        //Exclude deleted profiles or corrupted pictures.
    if(getimagesize($savedImage) > 0 ){

    //PHasher class call to hash the images to hexdecimal values or binary values.
        $hash = $I->FastHashImage($savedImage);
        $hex = $I->HashAsString($hash);

        //Store Facebook id and hashed values for the images in hexa values.
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO images(fid, hash) VALUES ('$fid', '$hex')");

        $initial++;
    } else {
        $initial++;
    }
}
}

?>
```

I didn't figure out how to do it, but what I am thinking of now is:

1- Divide into 1000 profiles for each loop and store them in an array.

```
    $items = array();
for($i=$fid; $i <= $fid+1000; $i++){

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$i.'/picture?width=378&height=378';
    $items[$i] = array($url);
}
```

but the results are incorrect I want to know how to fix the output of the array.

```
Array ( [28990] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28990/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28991] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28991/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28992] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28992/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28993] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28993/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28994] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28994/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28995] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28995/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28996] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28996/picture?width=378&height=378 )
[28997] => Array ( [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/28997/picture?width=378&height=378 )
```

2- Then I want to use the output array inside Mulit curl, allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously.

3- Check the output URLs if it's equal to the deleted profile if not pass it to be converted as a hash value using PHasher and store it inside the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have what you need, although I haven't been able to reach that kind of throughput (1000 parallel requests per sec)

I forgot where I got this before but I am using this to download reddit content:

```
class ParallelCurl {

    public $max_requests;
    public $options;
    public $outstanding_requests;
    public $multi_handle;

    public function __construct($in_max_requests = 10, $in_options = array()) {
        $this->max_requests = $in_max_requests;
        $this->options = $in_options;

        $this->outstanding_requests = array();
        $this->multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
    }

    //Ensure all the requests finish nicely
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->finishAllRequests();
    }

    // Sets how many requests can be outstanding at once before we block and wait for one to
    // finish before starting the next one
    public function setMaxRequests($in_max_requests) {
        $this->max_requests = $in_max_requests;
    }

    // Sets the options to pass to curl, using the format of curl_setopt_array()
    public function setOptions($in_options) {
        $this->options = $in_options;
    }

    // Start a fetch from the $url address, calling the $callback function passing the optional
    // $user_data value. The callback should accept 3 arguments, the url, curl handle and user
    // data, eg on_request_done($url, $ch, $user_data);
    public function startRequest($url, $callback, $user_data = array(), $post_fields = null, $headers = null) {
        if ($this->max_requests > 0)
            $this->waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow($this->max_requests);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->options);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if (isset($post_fields)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
        }
        if (is_array($headers)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }

        curl_multi_add_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);

        $ch_array_key = (int) $ch;
        $this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key] = array(
            'link_url' => $url,
            'callback' => $callback,
            'user_data' => $user_data,
        );

        $this->checkForCompletedRequests();
    }

    // You *MUST* call this function at the end of your script. It waits for any running requests
    // to complete, and calls their callback functions
    public function finishAllRequests() {
        $this->waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow(1);
    }

    // Checks to see if any of the outstanding requests have finished
    private function checkForCompletedRequests() {
        /*
          // Call select to see if anything is waiting for us
          if (curl_multi_select($this->multi_handle, 0.0) === -1)
          return;

          // Since something's waiting, give curl a chance to process it
          do {
          $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
          } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
         */
        // fix for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63411
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
            if (curl_multi_select($this->multi_handle) != -1) {
                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($this->multi_handle, $active);
                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            } else
                return;
        }

        // Now grab the information about the completed requests
        while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($this->multi_handle)) {

            $ch = $info['handle'];
            $ch_array_key = (int) $ch;

            if (!isset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key])) {
                die("Error - handle wasn't found in requests: '$ch' in " .
                    print_r($this->outstanding_requests, true));
            }

            $request = $this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key];
            $url = $request['link_url'];
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
            $callback = $request['callback'];
            $user_data = $request['user_data'];

            call_user_func($callback, $content, $url, $ch, $user_data);

            unset($this->outstanding_requests[$ch_array_key]);

            curl_multi_remove_handle($this->multi_handle, $ch);
        }
    }

    // Blocks until there's less than the specified number of requests outstanding
    private function waitForOutstandingRequestsToDropBelow($max) {
        while (1) {
            $this->checkForCompletedRequests();
            if (count($this->outstanding_requests) < $max)
                break;

            usleep(10000);
        }
    }

}
```

The way this works is you pass to ParallelCurl::startRequest() a URL and a callback function (could be anonymous), and this queues a download for this URL, then calls the function when the download finishes.

```
$pcurl = new ParallelCurl(10, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 1,
));

$pcurl->startRequest($url, function($data) {
     // download finished. $data is html or binary, whatever you requested
     echo $data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working but can you tell me how to save that output of the loop as an array it's saving as one element in the array only [0]

Comment: What do you mean save as an array? Just collect your URLs in an array and loop through that array passing each url to $pcurl->startRequest. See this: http://pastebin.com/rMJG1QjC. Run this (along with the class here) in command line and you may notice that the downloads may not be in order because they are not being saved in sequence but in parallel